# Finding a value in a row on another sheet and placing a value in the matching row and column header on current sheet if exists and 0 if it doesnt

Tags: excel, vba

So I'm having a little bit of trouble wrapping my head around how to do this. I have a table that looks like this on one sheet

```
ID    Answer1    Answer2    Answer3   Answer4
1     Apples     Oranges    Bananas   Grapes
2     Bananas    Grapes
3     Apples 
4     Oranges    Bananas
```

Then I have another table that looks like this on another sheet

```
ID   Apples    Oranges   Bananas   Grapes
1
2
3
4
```

What im trying to do is place a 1 in each column for the answer someone picked and 0 if they didn't pick it. So the result would look like the following:

```
ID   Apples   Oranges   Bananas   Grapes 
1      1        1         1         1
2      0        0         1         1
3      1        0         0         0
4      0        1         1         0
```

Im not sure what I would use to make this happen but If someone could guide me in the right direction it would be very appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a formula like this:

```
=COUNTIF(INDEX(Sheet1!$B$2:$E$5,MATCH($H2,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$5,0),0),I$1)
```

This requires that the IDs are unique in the lookup table or it will only bring over the first id that matches.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with some simple if logic.

```
=if('other sheet'!b2="Apples",1,0)
```

Copy that formula down through the rest of the table, and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this. You can copy it to every cell of sheet 2.

```
=IF(COUNTIF('Sheet1'!$A2:$D2;A$1)<>0;1;0)
```